# Perl write to html file not working

Tags: perl

I am running a perl script that is supposed to take gifs from one website, move them to another website, and write the links to an index.html file labeled by date. It does the move operation extremely well, but can't write to the index.html file. I have warnings turned on, but they aren't telling me why the script isn't performing the write operation.

The relevant part looks like this:

```
## Do some parsing to insert date information into index.html...
open(FILE, "<", $from);
my @index = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

## Don't just copy - change the date info so each page is well labeled...
my $line = '';  # declaration for foreach loop below
open(INDEX, ">", $to) or die "Can't open '$to': $!"; 

# open index.html to write to
foreach $line (@index){
$line =~  s/DATE/$months[$mon] $mday, $year at 3pm ET to next day at 3pm/;
print INDEX $line;
}
close(INDEX);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run it? What did you expect instead?

Comment: You could also check that `close(INDEX)` worked like you do fo the corresponding open.

Comment: What is the value of $to?  Maybe it is writing to some other directory.

Comment: Start your script in the debugger with `perl -d` then step through it printing variables as you go. You only need about 4 commands - `b 10` to break on line 10, `n` next statement, `p var` to print variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check that you opened `$from` successfully.

```
open(FILE, "<", $from) or die "$from: $!";
```

Other than that, there are a few other things you could check.

- What is the value of `$from`?
- How many records do you read into `@index`?
- What is the value of `$to`?